# Nifi - Update Remote Process Group through Rest API

Tags: apache-nifi, hortonworks-dataflow

We are using templates to package up some data transfer jobs between two nifi clusters, one acting as a sender, the other as the receiver. One of our jobs contains a remote process group and all worked fine at the point the template was created.

However when we deploy the template through our environments (dev, test, pre, prod), it is tedious and annoying to have to manually delete and a recreate a remote process group in the user interface. I'd like to automate this to simplify deploying templates and reduce the manual intervention.

1. Is it possible to update a remote processor group and its port configuration through the rest-api ?
2. Do I just use the REST api to create a new RPG with the correct configuration ?

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a JIRA to address this issue [1] which will be worked in conjunction with some of the ongoing Flow Registry (SDLC for flows) efforts. Until then, the best option would be (2) above.

[1] https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4526